# MongoDB how to access relational model and update

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, model

When I create a new user I want to access my user's role name and update.

If client is redirected with '/company/register' route my user role name will be 'company' by default if the client is redirected with '/user/register' user role name it will be guest or etc. I am new for MongoDB and NodeJS maybe my perspective totally wrong I am open to suggestion

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: ""
    },
    encrypted_password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        default: ""
    },
    user_role:[
        {
            role_name:{
                type:String
            },
            is_company:{
                type:Boolean,
                default:false
            },
            write:{
                type:Boolean,
                default:false
            },
            read:{
                type:Boolean,
                default:false
            },
            publish:{
                type:Boolean,
                default:false
            }
        }
    ],
    company:[
        {
            company_name:{
                type:String
            },
            address:{
                type:String
            }
        }
    ],


});
```

> My register route

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
        .then(company => {
            if (company) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    email: 'Email already exists'
                });
            }
            else {
                const newUser = new User({
                    // I want to access here
                    email: req.body.email,
                    encrypted_password: req.body.encrypted_password,
                    updated_at: Date.now()
                });
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) =>{bcrypt.hash(newUser.encrypted_password, salt, (err, hash) => {newUser.encrypted_password = hash;
                        // New user added
                        newUser
                            .save()
                            .then(user => res.json(user))
                            .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    })
                })
            }
        });
});
```

> I already tried this, of course, it doesn't work

```
const newUser = new User({
                    email: req.body.email,
                    encrypted_password: req.body.encrypted_password,
                    user_role.role_name: "company",
                    updated_at: Date.now()
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method

```
const company_user_role = {role_name:"company",is_company:true};
                const newUser = new User({
                    email: req.body.email,
                    encrypted_password: req.body.encrypted_password,
                    user_role: company_user_role,
                    updated_at: Date.now()
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a good solution. 
I prefer to get rid of memory allocation time.

I suggest the following object:

```
const tempUser = {};
tempUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    encrypted_password: req.body.encrypted_password,
    user_role: {
        role_name:"company",is_company:true
        },
    updated_at: Date.now()
}
const newUser = new User(tempUser);
```

**Based on the schema I think you need to use Array instead of an object(I'm talking about user_role). You can find it in the following part:**

```
const tempUser = {};
tempUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    encrypted_password: req.body.encrypted_password,
    user_role: [{
        role_name:"company",is_company:true
        }],
    updated_at: Date.now()
}
const newUser = new User(tempUser);
```